# Can game settings be changed dynamically?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I manipulate a game property using logic bricks. I can read the property in the following script and set the value of `bpy.context.scene.game_settings.stereo_eye_separation` which is changed as long the value is less than 5.0.

Unfortunately, setting this value during runtime has no effect.

Is there any 'update' method I'm supposed to call or another way to apply the changes?

```
import bge
import bpy

co = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
print( co )
sep = co.owner["eye_separation"]
print( " property:%f" % sep )
bpy.context.scene.game_settings.stereo_eye_separation = co.owner["eye_separation"]
print( "gs.stereo:%f" % bpy.context.scene.game_settings.stereo_eye_separation )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bpy` module is unlikely to have any effect during game play; you should use `bge` instead. Try [bge.render.setEyeSeparation()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bge.render.html#bge.render.setEyeSeparation).